# Electromagnet inside a conducting shell

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I am asking this to enquire whether what I am thinking is right or not because I have not heard or read about any such example ( which came to mind just now).*

Consider an electromagnet ( I can change the current in electromagnet and hence its magnetic field) which is placed inside a conducting shell. A large current flows through the electromagnet and it produces a large magnetic field. Now I keep on changing the current in the electromagnet (somehow very quickly ).

*Will the conducting shell heat up ? I ask this because I don't think Eddy currents should be generated since div B =0 and hence the flux of of B through this closed surface ( shell) is 0. Neglect external effects.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the magnetic field changes with time then it will induce eddy currents in the conducting shell, which dissipate energy as heat. The fact that the total magnetic flux through the shell is zero is irrelevant. Heating effects ($I^2R$) do not depend on the direction of the eddy currents.

Comment: The point was that the total flux through the surface was 0 before & after increasing the current (isn't it ) . So rate of change of flux =0. Then there can't be any V & hence no current .

Comment: Think of the spherical shell as being divided into rings perpendicular to the symmetry axis of the magnetic field. The flux through each of these rings changes, so a current flows around the ring.

Comment: Ok I was trying to manipulate the div B =0 condition. What I had in mind was that if the total flux through a surface can be kept 0 ( so a closed surface , used to sloving Faraday's law for open plates ,etc) always then the rate of change of flux through the surface would be zero too and by faraday's law the current would be zero too. Is this logic right apart from your ring explanation. Do currents induce when we take closed surfaces because flux through close surface is 0  , div B =0

Comment: The surface used to calculate induced current must be enclosed by a loop. If the surface is closed, there is no loop. The surface used does not have to coincide with the shell - it can be an imaginary disk in space. ... See [wiki article on EM Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction#Maxwell.E2.80.93Faraday_equation).

Comment: So I see we cannot take closed surface  because then the magnetic flux will be 0 anyway (out of scope of flux rule ). Is what I get right ? Never thought about the use of loop & surface .